# Why UITextField has to be populated for UIButton to disappear as subview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

when I focus on a UITextField control, I add button as subview. when I remove the focus from UITextField, I remove the add button. This works when there is some text in the UITextField. But when there is no text, the button does not go away.

```
Q. How can I remove the UIButton from UITextField when the UITextField is empty. 
I also want to be able to show *default* placeholder-text for UITextField when add button is removed.
```

Here is my code to add and remove unbutton as subview

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    if(textField == txtToEmailAddress)
    {
        txtToEmailAddress.rightView = button;
        txtToEmailAddress.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddEmailAddress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.txtToEmailAddress addSubview:button];
    }
    if(textField == txtCallPhoneNum)
    {
        txtCallPhoneNum.rightView = button;
        txtCallPhoneNum.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddPhoneNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.txtCallPhoneNum addSubview:button];
    }
    if(textField == txtTextNumbers)
    {
        txtTextNumbers.rightView = button;
        txtTextNumbers.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddTextNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.txtTextNumbers addSubview:button];
    }

    return YES;
}



- (BOOL)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIButton *button = nil;


    if(textField == txtToEmailAddress)
    {
        button = (UIButton *)[txtToEmailAddress.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if(textField == txtCallPhoneNum)
    {
        button = (UIButton *)[txtCallPhoneNum.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    if(textField == txtTextNumbers)
    {
        button = (UIButton *)[txtTextNumbers.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
    }

    if (button != nil)
    {
            button.hidden = YES;
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Here is the add button in the empty UITextField that needs to go away.

[image]

Comment: Check whether it gets into the if block at all - meaning the pointer to the textfield is still there..

Comment: does all the three textFields have placeholder text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine.But problem is with the index of button and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method

**Firstly**

The index of the button is 2 if you have a placeholder text and text in textfield

**Next** the method should be implemented like this

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

And the finally adding some optimization to your code, the working code looks like this

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
     textField.rightView = button;
     textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
     [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AddTextNumber:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     [textField addSubview:button];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIButton *button = nil;
    NSLog(@"textField>>%@",[textField.subviews description]);
    if([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        button = (UIButton *)[textField.subviews objectAtIndex:2];
    else
        button = (UIButton *)[textField.subviews objectAtIndex:1];

    if (button != nil)
    {
        button.hidden = YES;
        [button removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This should work perfectly same as your textbox's Focus() method in dotnet :) **No need to populate textField for hiding button** .Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Do the button remove action in this block..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(newString.length==0) {
         button.hidden=YES;
         textField.text=@"Default text";
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this works but not a good solution. I have to add blank characters to textField.text to make it think that there is some thing in UITextField. Why the UITextField has to be populated for UIButton to disappear???

Comment: instead of `textField.text=@"Default text";` just use placeholder property. and `[button removeFromSuperview];` otherwise this is fine for that @dotnet-practitioner 's requirement

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

(in a subclass of UITextField)

```
- (UITextFieldViewMode)rightViewMode
{
    return [self.text isEqualToString:@""] ? UITextFieldViewModeNever : UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}
```